# How to reset an std::pair?

Tags: c++, std-pair

I'm writing some code using an `std::pair<double,double> foo`. The code takes input data, does some calculation, and saves the output in `foo`. Next, I want to reset all my variables to be able to start a new read-in / calculation. How can I reset this `std::pair`? Or what would you recommend doing?

I've already looked at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair , so I know there is no std::pair::clear() function. It's more about what you'd recommend on how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Set both components of the pair to zero?

Comment: If you want to reset the content of your pair you can do this: `std::pair<double, double> p = {1.0, 2.0}; p = {};`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I basically just want to reset, as if I had just created a new `std::pair`. Updated the question.

Comment: Why not create a new std::pair @nilsernst?

Comment: `std::pair`s don't need resetting, you can just overwrite them as vahancho pointed out or alternatively like that: `foo = std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0);`

Comment: Thanks, then I'll just override.

Comment: The new read-in will overwrite the `pair` data anyway. You don't have to do it manually.

Comment: @CinCout But *are* we reading in next? If we continue like `p.first += someCalculatedValue;` we need explicit 'reset'...

Comment: @Aconcagua That's the best the OP is going to get with prose and no code!

Comment: Thanks for the further comments! @CinCout: I got what I wanted from the above answers, so everything's fine. ;)